# How to interpret the meaning of "c’est-à-dire" in this context?

Tags: sens, usage

> Du travail à l'hôpital de XXX ? **C’est-à-dire** que je ne suis pas à sec... Désolée.

The use of "c’est-à-dire" does not seem logical here. After all, the speaker wants to say:

> Du travail à l'hôpital de XXX ? **C'est pas comme si** j'étais à sec... Désolée.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*C'est à dire*, or *Comment dire...* is often used when you're embarassed, like you pretend you're looking for the best words to say something embarassing...

Here it's a way to say *I'm embarassed to say how bad it is to work there so I won't, instead I tell that I'm not that poor that I would go to work there, you'll make the conclusions you want*... in of course a more subtil way.

I guess in english you would maybe say *Well ...* :

*Work at hospital XXX ? Well... it's not like I were dead broke !*

Comment: That last line isn't idiomatic English; it should be "It's not like *I'm* dead broke." However, I'm not sure I'd translate this that way. What about "I'd have to be broke!"

Comment: I'm not an english specialist, I used were because there's a not written `if` after `like`. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71661/in-which-type-of-situations-we-can-use-i-were . But yours does sound better. About the translation "I'd have to be broke" it sounds more direct, less subtle, but it might be how english would say.

Answer (score 0):

According to the dictionnary Larousse :

"*C'est-à-dire*" is an adverb used to give/introduced an explanation, a restriction or a correction/rectification.

"*C'est-à-dire*" is also used here to get listen that what we will say is the consequence of what someone else said or did or the explanation we have to tell about.